# PC won't power on

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

I shut down my computer two days ago, when it was functioning with no major issues. About 24 hours later I tried to turn it back on and it wouldn't respond, not even the fans. I could only see the flickering ethernet green light (when the cord was plugged in). There was no burning smell at all.

I tested the PSU with the usual paper clip method, bridgding the green and ground pins of the PSU-motherboard connector, and there was no response whatsoever. Of course I tried plugging the cord in a few sockets.

Since the problem is probably in the PSU I might just buy a new one, but I'm really not much of an expert on the subject, so should I take my PC to an IT technician?

Also, I'm curious about how the PSU could have failed after shut down. I couldn't find any information regarding potential causes.

It's worthy to mention that my PC (all of its components) is almost 8 years old. Also, last year I was doing home improvements in my house, so lots of dust floated around and ended up in the inside of the PC case, which I had to exhaustively clean. After that an irritating, high pitched whirring noise persisted when the PC was on, which I thought was coil whine.

Lastly, I should mention that this failure occured in the context of a more extensive (and maybe also intensive) use of my computer, since I don't use it much throughout the year, but I game during the holidays. Let me know if you need any specs.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop. This type of problem is most probably a hardware issue & impossible to diagnose in text.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your PSU unit is faulty as it doesn't turn on if you bridge the wires. Please note that it is also possible that the psu is not turning on because there is no load connected when you test it. Some PSUs have a built-in protection for that. Take it to an IT technician and he will help you with your issue.